# How to get google merchant_id to access google merchant account of user using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I need `merchant_id` in response of google authorization

**I tried this**

I have followed this link:
https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/accounts/authinfo#try-it

I have oauth credential. I have tried to access link "https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/accounts/authinfo?key={YOUR_API_KEY}", in this key I had added secret key of oauth. But when I called this link I got error response message

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

**Need solution:**

How can I access this link with rails application and get the merchant_id in the callback response.

Comment: I have also faced same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
 response = HTTParty.get("https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/accounts/authinfo",
                    :headers => {"Authorization" => "Bearer" +" "+ token["access_token"]})
```

Comment: I have followed your code but I keep getting kind got value but merchant id is missing